# DialogFragment findFragmentByTag return null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview, android-dialogfragment

I use `DialogFragment` contain a `webview`. After show the `DialogFragment` , when pressed back button, the app will return to the activity view. If pressed show DialogFragment button, the webview load the init url again. But my requirement is that if second time open the DialogFragment , i want the webview show page last time loaded. How can i achieve this?

My current thought is keep the DialogFragment instance, when push the show button then check if activity already has the DialogFragment. But in my code, the `findFragmentByTag` always return null ,what's the problem? Or I should do some work in the DialogFragment?

main activity code:

```
mcWebViewDialog m_webviewDialog = null;

public void showWebviewDialog()
{

    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev=fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("mcWebDialog");

    if(prev!=null)
    {
        Log.v("seayoung","m_webviewDialog not null");
        fragmentTransaction.show(prev);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.v("seayoung","m_webviewDialog null");
        m_webviewDialog=mcWebViewDialog.newInstance();
        m_webviewDialog.set_loadurl("file:///android_asset/input.html");
        m_webviewDialog.show(fragmentManager,"mcWebDialog");
    }
}
```

WebViewDialog code:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

         //other code 
         m_webView.loadUrl(m_loadurl);

        return m_webView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you press back your dialog fragment is destroyed and is removed from backstack, hence you are getting null while performing `findFragmentByTag`, well it wont be a good idea to hold the view when user presses back, but as an alternative you can try caching the created fragment locally, like this.

```
HashMap<String,WeakReference<DialogFragment>> dialogMap = new HashMap<>();

// call this before callin `show`
dialogMap.put(TAG,new WeakReference<>(YOUR_FRAGMENT));
```

and next time, you can perform this

```
DialogFragment prev=fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("mcWebDialog");
if(prev == null){
     prev = dialogMap.get("mcWebDialog").get();
}
if(prev!=null){
   Log.v("seayoung","m_webviewDialog not null");
   fragmentTransaction.show(prev);
}
```

Comment: `prev = dialogMap.get("mcWebDialog").get();` but how to show it?

Comment: finally, I choose hide the dialog rather than store it.